# Setting a checkbox "check" property in React

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, default-value

I am having a very annoying issue with React and checkboxes. The application I am working with requires a list of checkboxes that represent settings that are persisted in the back-end. **There is an option to restore the settings to their original state**.

At first, I created a component that has an object like a map of settings. Each setting has a key and a boolean value. Hence:

```
{
    bubbles: true,
    gregory: false
}
```

Is to be represented as:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="bubbles" checked="checked" />
<input type="checkbox" value="gregory" />
```

Now, it seems React is ignorant about how a checkbox is supposed to work. I don't want to set the checkboxes' values, I want the "checked" property.

Yet, if I try something like this:

```
<input
    type="checkbox"
    value={setting}
    checked={this.settings[setting]}
    onChange={this.onChangeAction.bind(this)}
/>
```

I get this warning:

> Warning: AwesomeComponent is changing an uncontrolled input of type checkbox to be controlled. Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component. More info: [*some useless docs page I read several times to no avail*]

So I decided to create another component to wrap each individual checkbox and I got this:

```
<input
    type="checkbox"
    checked={this.state.checked}
    onChange={this.onChangeAction.bind(this)}
/>
```

Now the `checked` is a property present directly in my state.

This yields the same warning, so I tried using `defaultChecked`:

```
<input
    type="checkbox"
    defaultChecked={this.state.checked}
    onChange={this.onChangeAction.bind(this)}
/>
```

Which makes the warning disappear, but now it is unable to reset the `checked` value to the default one. So I tried playing with the method `componentWillReceiveProps`, this way I am quite sure my state is correct, `this.state.checked` is correct and the component renders again.

And it does. But the checkbox remains as it was originally.
For now I left that ugly warning and I am using `checked`.
How do I fix this thing so the warning goes away?

I was thinking that perhaps there is a way to force-re-render the component, so it captures the new `defaultChecked` value and uses it. But I don't know how to do that. Perhaps suppress the warning **only** for this component? Is that possible? Perhaps there is something else that can be done?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

The problem arises if you set the `checked` property of your checkbox to `null` or `undefined`.

Those are "falsy" values in JS. However, [React treats a value of `null` as if the property was not set](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/controlled-input-null-value.html) at all. Since the default state of a checkbox is unchecked, everything will work fine though. If you then set `checked` to `true`, React thinks the property suddenly comes into existence! This is when React figures you switched from uncontrolled to controlled, since now the prop `checked` exists.

In your example, you can get rid of this warning by changing `checked={this.settings[setting]}` to `checked={!!this.settings[setting]}`. Notice the double bang (`!!`). They will convert `null` or `undefined` to `false` (and leave `true` alone), so React will register your `checked` property with a value of `false` and start off with a controlled form component.

I had this problem too and I, too, read the [docs about controlled-components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) several times to no avail, but I finally figured it out, so I thought I'd share. Also, since [version 15.2.0](https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/7003), normal inputs are triggered to be controlled by setting `value`, while checkboxes are initialized as controlled by setting `checked`, regardless of their `value` property, which added a bit to the confusion.

Comment: Over an hour wasted because I thought I understood the issue due to a very specific warning message from React. Nope. It was an undefined variable becoming defined later. Thank you.

Comment: I cannot thumbs-up this answer enough. I was conditionally adding and removing the `checked` attribute itself, which was good practice back in the plain-jane HTML days. I spent twenty minutes puzzled as to why this error message was occurring. The ReactJS error message really should have a special case acknowledging the inconsistent weirdness that is the HTML checkbox input so that others don't bump into this as well.

Comment: Incredible answer :) And that's a nice trick that I didn't know about (using the double bang to instantly cast to a boolean value)

Comment: I also didn't realize that checkboxes are controlled by the 'checked' attribute and not 'value'. I was getting some weird behavior until I found this post. Thank you! https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

Answer (score 17):

Amoebe's answer is correct, but I think there's a cleaner solution than the double bank (`!!`). Simply add a [defaultProps](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html#default-prop-values) property with value `false` for `checked` prop of your Checkbox component:

```
import React from 'react';

const Checkbox = ({checked}) => (
  <div>
      <input type="checkbox" checked={checked} />
  </div>
);

Checkbox.defaultProps = {
  checked: false
};

export default Checkbox;
```

Comment: How about just `{checked = false}` in the function declaration?

Comment: yeah this seems like overkill to me

Answer (score 10):

Basically, the `defaultChecked` means you don't want to control the input – it just renders with this value and then there is no way to control it. Also, `value` shouldn't be used, but `checked` instead, so your second code should be correct. And you shouldn't use them both simultaneously.

```
<input
    type="checkbox"
    checked={this.state.checked}
    onChange={this.onChangeAction.bind(this)}
/>
```

Can you create a small fiddle with this behaviour?

Comment: His problem is because this.state.checked is undefined, rather than false.
So something like this is a bit safer:

<input
    type="checkbox"
    checked={!!this.state.checked}
    onChange={this.onChangeAction.bind(this)}
/>

Answer (score 5):

Here is an answer using hooks should you choose to convert the class component to a functional one...

```
export default Checklist = () => {
  const [listOfItems, setListOfItems] = useState([
    {name: 'bubbles', isChecked: true},
    {name: 'gregory', isChecked: false}
  ]);

  const updateListOfItems = (itemIndex, isChecked) => {
    const updatedListOfItems = [...listOfItems];
    updatedListOfItems[itemIndex].isChecked = isChecked;
    setListOfItems(updatedListOfItems);
  }

  return (
    {listOfitems.map((item, index) =>
      <index key={index} type="checkbox" checked={item.isChecked} onChange={() => updateListOfItems(index, !item.isChecked)} />
    )}
  )
}
```

Comment: This helped me but there's typos

Comment: @Jeremy Thanks, I updated the answer to fix the typo.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign your data to the state and then make use of the checked property associated with the individual checkbox to set the state as

```
{   this.state.data.map(function(item, index) {
      return (
        
        <input type="checkbox" checked={item.value} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, index)}/>
        
      );
    }.bind(this))
    }
```

Sample Data in state is as

```
data: [{name:'bubbles', value: true}, {name:'gregory', value: false}]
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/mayank_shubham/69z2wepo/53831/)

Answer (score 0):

What finally worked, combining other answers:

```
const [categories, setCategories] = useState(
    [
        {
            field: 'Label 1',
            checked: true
        },
        {
            field: 'Label 2',
            checked: false
        },
        {
            field: 'Label 3',
            checked: false
        }
    ]
)
const updateList = (item, isChecked) => {
    const updatedList = [...categories];
    updatedList[item].checked = isChecked;
    setCategories(updatedList);
}
... in your markup:
{
  categories.map((item, index) =>
    <div key = {item.field}>
      <label>
        <span>{item.field}</span>
        <input key={index}
               type="checkbox"
               checked={item.checked}
               onChange={() => updateList(index, !item.checked)}
         />
      </label>
    </div>
  )
}
```