# How to display data with id React Js and Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I'm working on a project, and I would like to display some data from my firebase database,

I can show some of them, but I want to display the rest of the data of my "listClients" on a box, linked to the checkbox with the id.

listClients.js it's where i map the data from the db

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import * as firebase from "firebase";
import { Table, InputGroup } from "react-bootstrap";
class ListClients extends React.Component {
  state = {
    loading: true
  };

  componentWillMount() {
    const ref = firebase.database().ref("listClients");
    ref.on("value", snapshot => {
      this.setState({ listClients: snapshot.val(), loading: false });
    });
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.loading) {
      return <h1>Chargement...</h1>;
    }

    const clients = this.state.listClients.map((client, i) => (
      <tr key={i}>
        <td>
          <input id={client.id} type="checkbox" onChange={this.cbChange} />
        </td>
        <td>{client.nom}</td>
        <td>{client.prenom}</td>
      </tr>
    ));
    const clientsAdresses = this.state.listClients.map((clientAdresse, i) => (
      <tr key={i}>
        <td id={clientAdresse.id}>{clientAdresse.adresse}</td>
      </tr>
    ));

    return (
      <>
        <Table className="ContentDesign" striped bordered hover>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th></th>

              <th>First Name</th>
              <th>Last Name</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>{clients}</tbody>
        </Table>

        <Table className="ContentDesign" striped bordered hover>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Adresse : </th>
            </tr>
          </thead>


          <tbody>{clientsAdresses}</tbody>


        </Table>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default ListClients;
```

my data : [image]

I only want the "adresse" of the id where the checkbox is check 
[image]

Thank you

ERROR : 
[image]

Comment: That error is a different problem.  You get that error when you try to display an object in React.  You'll need to pull your response apart before trying to display it.  To keep track of what's checked, google "controlled components" and see if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39120007/setting-a-checkbox-check-property-in-react

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve the adresse from the database then use the following code:

```
componentWillMount() {
const ref = firebase.database().ref("listClients");
    ref.on("value", snapshot => {
       snapshot.forEach((subSnap) => {
      let address = subSnap.val().adresse;
      });
    });
  }
```

First add a reference to node `listClients` the using `forEach` you can iterate and retrieve the `adresse`

---

If you want to get the `adresse` according to the id, then you can use a query:

```
const ref = firebase.database().ref("listClients").orderByChild("id").equalTo(0);
```

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33117449/invariant-violation-objects-are-not-valid-as-a-react-child https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41604539/objects-are-not-valid-as-a-react-child

Comment: You are displaying an object try and display a value for example `snapshot.key`

Comment: I can display this but only on the console.log, I don't know how to display on a h1 for example

Comment: Read this also https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_state.asp

Comment: Nice thank you, it's working, I display every address, but now when I click on a button radio I would like just the areas where the radio is checked