# React '...' expected error using props and ternary operator

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello I am getting as error in a React app '...' expected ts(1005). I do not know hat I am doing wring I have used these operators in other parts of the application and other with no problem. props.todoCompChecked has true or false. I used another boolean and console logged props.todoCompChecked but I get the same error and it consoles the correct value. Does anone know why I would be getting this issues?

`<input type="checkbox" onClick={() => props.todoComp(props.id)} {props.todoCompChecked ? "checked" : null} />`

[Screen shot of error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWNQ4.png)

This is the full component

```
import Button from './Button'

const Todo = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <label className="p-2 text-blue-700">Completed?</label>
            <input type="checkbox" onClick={() => props.todoComp(props.id)} {props.todoCompChecked ? "checked" : null} />
            <h4 className='p-2 text-2xl bg-blue-400 rounded-2xl' >{props.todoText} </h4>
            <Button doWhat="Delete" toDelete={props.toDelete} id={props.id} />
        </div>
    )
}
export default Todo;
```

Comment: You forgot an attribute before the `{props.todoCompChecked ? "checked" : null}`

Comment: @Phil `<Foo {someExpression}` is not valid. An attribute is needed. `<Foo someProp={someExpression}`.

Comment: @CertainPerformance thanks TIL (still new to React / JSX). I've found an applicable duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `checked` attribute like any other. React is intelligent enough to exclude the attribute if the value given is null. Just do `checked={props.todoCompChecked || null}`. If the prop is `true` the `checked` attribute will be present, otherwise it will not.

It may be better to set it to a true or false, rather than null, otherwise you may run into a warning about a component changing an input from uncontrolled to controlled. So you could do `checked={!!props.todoCompChecked}` instead. See this answer for a detailed explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39709700/12431728

> The problem arises if you set the checked property of your checkbox to null or undefined.

> Those are a "falsy" values in JS, however React treats a value of null as if the property was not set at all. Since the default state of a checkbox is unchecked, everything will work fine though. If you then set checked to true React thinks the property suddenly comes into existence! This is when React figures you switched from uncontrolled to controlled, since now the prop checked exists.

> In your example you can get rid of this warning by changing checked={this.settings[setting]} to checked={!!this.settings[setting]}. Notice the double bang (!!). They will convert null or undefined to false (and leave true alone), so React will register your checked property with a value of false and start off with a controlled form component.

Comment: OP already said that `todoCompChecked` is Boolean

Comment: Yes, but not passing it to a `checked` attribute.

Comment: I was just addressing your comment ~ _"It may be better to set it to a true or false"_

Comment: Indeed. I should've been more clear by saying set the checked attribute value to true or false (rather than null), not the value assigned to `todoCompChecked`.