# How do I control input checkbox "checked" state with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox

I am working on an application that has a form and radio buttons.

For one of the radio buttons, it has an option that can be toggled on/off with a checkbox.

I want the checkbox to be disabled if the respective radio button is NOT selected, its default behavior to work when is it active, and for it to be disabled AND unchecked if a different radio button is then selected.

I have gotten all of those behaviors to work, but React is throwing an exception that says,

> app-index.js:31 Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input to be controlled. This is likely caused by the value changing from undefined to a defined value, which should not happen. Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.

My "working" solution:

```
 const [checkboxActive, setCheckboxActive] = useState<boolean | undefined>(false);

 const handleOptionClick = (option?: string) => {
    setSelected(true);
    if (option) {
      setEveryOtherLetterSelected(true);
      setCheckboxActive(undefined);
    } else {
      setEveryOtherLetterSelected(false);
      setCheckboxActive(false);
    }
  }

<input type="checkbox" name="first" disabled={everyOtherLetterSelected ? false : true} checked={checkboxActive} />
```

From this thread ([Setting a checkbox "check" property in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39120007/setting-a-checkbox-check-property-in-react)), I see that this is a weird thing with React and checkbox type inputs where its "checked" value is either a boolean or undefined. I have tried putting the "!!" in front of the condition (`!!checkboxActive`), but that changes the behavior.

Is there a more acceptable way to do this where React won't yell at me?

Edit:

I have tried the !! operator in different places, like everywhere I had an "undefined" value. I also messed around with no undefined values for the checkbox and all undefined, but to no avail.

Comment: Could you please clarify how `!!` changes the behavior?

Comment: @MichaelLiu Yes, when I put the `!!` in front of checkboxActive like `!!checkboxActive`, the box is uncheckable even when it is active.

Comment: Try adding an `onClick` handler to the checkbox that updates the value of `checkboxActive`.

Comment: @MichaelLiu Hi, Michael, this did not work for me, unfortunately. It makes the warning go away, but it doesn't uncheck the checkbox when a different radio button is selected. I did use this onClick idea for another idea though, so thank you, and thank you for the help in the first place.

Comment: To uncheck the checkbox, call setCheckboxActive(false) when the other radio button is selected.

Comment: @MichaelLiu Thank you. I do have that in my code already.

Answer (score -1):

maybe try this:
`checked={checkboxActive === undefined ? false : checkboxActive}`

Comment: Thank you so much for this, but unfortunately this makes the active checkbox not "checkable".